# Asynchronous database inserts - python + mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am making a utility in which I need to extract tweets for a user and store them in database.   Twitter API only sends 20 tweets in one call and to retrieve more tweets, you need to page through the tweets 20 at a time. So instead of synchronously reading tweets from Twitter API and waiting to insert into DB, I want to start the database inserts asynchronously to optimize the process.
How can I achieve this with Python and Mysql?
**Pseudo-code** for this can be written as (not checked for syntax validity):-

```
    def readTweets():
       x=0
       while true: 
          tweets= twitterAPI.getusertimeline(id='twitterUser',count=20,page=x)
          #Need to know how to call the below function asynchronously
          callDBSaveAsynchronously(tweets)
          if len(tweets) < 20: break
          x=x+1

    def callDBSaveAsynchronously(tweets):
        for tweet in tweets:
            mysqldb.insertTweet(tweet)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With Postgres, [use twitter_fdw](https://github.com/umitanuki/twitter_fdw) to directly `SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE from_user='twitterUser';`

Comment: you could relegate each set of tweets or tweet page url you want insert to a job queue, and have a pool of workers to insert those tweets http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

Comment: Thanks, RabbitMQ makes lots of sense.... Do you know if python objects can be passed as messages to the queue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a third-party MySQL driver called [ultramysql](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql) that can take advantage of [gevent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/0.13.8) for async inserts. You could avoid threads that way. It worked great for me on a recent project.